# NullPointerException in TreeItem.branchExpandedEvent() trying to getGraphic

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to call `event.getSource().getGraphic()` in a branch expanded event of a `TreeItem` so that I can set a different icon, but I keep getting `NullPointerException`, and I can't figure out why. I can set the icon successfully when setting up the cell factory, but when I listen for the branch expanded event to do the same, it doesn't work. Here's how I'm setting up the tree (from the initialize event in my controller):

```
tree.setCellFactory(param -> new TreeCell<File>() {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(File item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setText("");
            setGraphic(null);
        } else {
            setText(item.getName());
            Image icon = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("folder.png"));
            setGraphic(new ImageView(icon));
        }
    }
});
```

This works fine and dandy.

Here's my event listener where the `ImageView` is null for some reason (also being added in the initialize event in my `TreeView` controller):

```
File home = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));
TreeItem<File> root = new TreeItem<>(home);
tree.setRoot(root);

root.addEventHandler(TreeItem.branchExpandedEvent(), event -> {
    TreeItem source = event.getSource();
    ImageView img = (ImageView)source.getGraphic(); // this is null!
    Image icon = Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("folder-open.png"));
    img.setImage(icon);
});
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm using Java 1.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're accessing the `graphic` property of the `TreeItem`, not the `graphic` property of the `TreeCell` that is set to a value != `null`. You need to handle this in the `TreeCell` instead. Furthermore you probably should use the `disclosureNode` property to replace the arrow. Also it's better to reuse the `Image`s:

```
final Image closedImage = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("folder.png"));
final Image openImage = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("folder-open.png"));

tree.setCellFactory(param -> new TreeCell<File>() {

    {
        final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        imageView.setFitWidth(20);
        imageView.setFitHeight(20);

        final ChangeListener<Boolean> expansionListener = new WeakChangeListener<>((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            imageView.setImage(newValue ? openImage : closedImage);
        });

        // add change listener to expanded property of item
        treeItemProperty().addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (oldValue != null) {
                oldValue.expandedProperty().removeListener(expansionListener);
            }
            if (newValue != null) {
                newValue.expandedProperty().addListener(expansionListener);
                expansionListener.changed(null, null, newValue.isExpanded()); // trigger for initial value
            }
        });

        setDisclosureNode(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateItem(File item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);

        setText((empty || item == null) ? "" : item.getName());
    }
});
```

Comment: That solution actually removes the triangles, which I want to keep. However, I've since realised that I can just check this.getTreeItem().isExpanded() in the updateItem method in the cellFactory and set the graphic there (which is what I probably should have done in the first place). Thanks for your help.